# SSIS Package tasks execution detail

Tags: ssis, package

We have deployed SSIS packages in one of our Prod Server using  source server as another Prod DB server, in this job I have many packages (almost 10 packages) with many tasks and sub tasks.

The job is executing successfully and we can find the each package execution start time and end time using job steps.

Now we would like to know each task execution in each package.

Please let me know how where I can find each take execution time or log info for each task?

Please suggest?

Answer (score 3):

At the time of SSIS package development, enable logging (Open BIDS>SSIS Menu>Log Events).  You can define how you want to log the information (file type) and what to log.  You should be able to set the appropriate log details as per your requirements.